# Why is there a red line next to my logo?

Tags: html, css, image

I have an odd redline next to my logo, and I can't for the life of me work out why.

Take a look: 
http://www.pdf-explode.com.au/index.php

Here's the red line I'm talking about:
http://www.bounceapp.com/66618

- I've tried looking at all the borders, there's no red.
- searched through backgrounds, no red.
- inspector can't inspect it.
- it's not in the image

Let me know if you can find it.

Comment: Usually when debugging visual issues, it's often best to specify the browser, helpful even to know what platform you're on and best of all, a screenshot is more than necessary in those cases. So provide a bit more info.

Comment: @20100 Good feedback. Sorry I was using Chrome Dev. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The background is repeated (the red line is a part of the letter `D`), so add: `no-repeat` to your css

Comment: Crazy to see how fast people give the same answer here xD At least that confirms that I was thinking in the right direction ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's the `repeat` of the background image on `#menu a.logo` (so it is the `D` of Document showing up again to the right). Remove the repeat.

Answer (score 2):

your css:

```
#menu a.logo {
    background: url("../images/logo1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 45px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -10000px !important;
    top: 5px;
    width: 265px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

the correct css:

```
#menu a.logo {
    background: url("../images/logo1.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; //edited
    height: 45px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: -10000px !important;
    top: 5px;
    width: 263px; //edited
    z-index: 10;
}
```

your logo's width is `263px;`

Answer (score 2):

This is because your logo starts repeating itself. The line is coming from the red "D". add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` or shorten the logo width for about 2 pixels.